# How to open file in Sublime Text 2 from command line in specific project windows

Tags: windows, sublimetext2

I want to open file in sublime text from commandline, like this (I am using Sublime Text 2 for Windows):

```
c:\path\sublime_text.exe" file.cpp
```

But I have 1-3 open windows/projects and I want to specify in which window the file should be open. Is it possible to do this?

I tried `--project` command line switch but it opens new project window every time.

Without `--project`, the files are open in last used sublime text window and even files from one open project directory are opened in the last used window (and this can be other project window).

I know I can solve this by edit everything in one project/one window but I prefer to have one window for every project if possible.